# How can I make an object accessible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding and I've been trying to solve this problem.

I want to get the user's input [from this input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtLM.png) and write it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37AyR.png). I managed to write this code

This is the first script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class SubmitButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
   object myObject = new Object();


   public Button btnClick;

   public InputField inputUser;

   void Start()
   {
       btnClick.onClick.AddListener(GetInputOnClickHandler);
   }


    public void GetInputOnClickHandler()
    {
        Debug.Log("Input is " + inputUser.text);
        inputUser.text = myObject.ToString();

    } 
}
```

And this is the second script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class txtScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Text txtMy = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        txtMy.text = "Test" + ToString(SubmitButton.myObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to acces myObject from SubmitButton but I got this error:
`Assets\Scripts\txtScript.cs(12,53): error CS0122:  'SubmitButton.myObject' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

I've tried to solve this but I can't manage to do it.
I used static modifiers/Getters & Setters but maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: You can shoot trigger and subscribe to your button to get it: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.OnSubmit.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Button.html

Comment: Hi, welcome. You will need to declare it `public` to be accessible outside of the class, but where do you instantiate the `SubmitButton` class e.g. `var submitButton = new SubmitButton();`?

Comment: what is this supposed to do exactly? if `Object` refers to `UnityEngine.Object` then you are not allowed to use `new` to create one. And in general if you don't write an accessor in `c#` per default everything inside a class is `private`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest, at least while you're still familiarising yourself with coding, to simplify this down and just use one script which references the text input, submit button and text display.

This can be achieved by adding a line and adjusting a line in your first script `SubmitButton`, and removing or disabling the second `txtScript` (as it is not needed).

Declare an additional field for the displayText (this should reference the GameObject shown in your second screenshot)

```
public Text displayText;
```

Then on the submit action, directly update the displayText text to match the inputUser text

```
public void GetInputOnClickHandler()
{
    Debug.Log("Input is " + inputUser.text);
    displayText.text = inputUser.text;
}
```

Also derHugo mentions, it is not possible to create or meaningfully use the base `Object` class directly. Most objects you create & access via script in Unity are `Components` (e.g. Text, Button, Rigidbody, Renderer, etc.), `Monobehaviour` scripts which are attached to `GameObjects` (e.g. these scripts), or regular C# classes and structs which you have written to work in tandem with the former two (this last one being the only type you would usually explicitly instantiate using the `new` keyword).